# for each Name from CSV write to each output file replacing the word 00000 to name for example 1 output Henry and so on

Tags: powershell, for-loop, replace, each

I am trying to use every (Name) to be use in on CSV to replace (00000) written on on each file that I am exporting.
the file already contains the word 00000

csv file contains:

```
FullName             Name    LastWriteTime
\\remotecomputer\    Henry   4/30/2020  3:44:57 PM
\\remotecompter\     Magy    12/7/2020  9:04:28 PM
```

first txt should look like this
@echo off
if /i "%UserName%" neq "Henry" exit

second txt should look like this
@echo off
if /i "%UserName%" neq "Magy" exit

original Config.txt looks like this
@echo off
if /i "%UserName%" neq "00000" exit

Code:

```
$source = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert source path'
Import-Csv C:\$source-PREP.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} |ForEach-Object {Get-Content c:\Config.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '00000',"$_.Name"} |Out-File c:\$_.txt  -Force}
```

Comment: Please show us the (sanitized) content of `c:\Config.txt` so we know what the source looks like.

Comment: What is your question? :)

Comment: here is the Config.txt file contest

Comment: @echo off
if /i "%UserName%" neq "00000" exit
REM ---- Send Message to User About Not Interrupting the Copying of Their Profile ----

Comment: I am trying to use every (Name) from CSV to replace (00000) written on on each file that I am exporting.
the file already contains the word 00000

Comment: But there isn't any `00000` in your sample file? Please [edit] the question and include sample input and desired output. If there are edge cases, add some examples about those - and how they would be handled - too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** you want to do:

- read a template file `c:\Config.txt` which contains `"00000"` as placeholder
- read a csv file `C:\Something-PREP.csv` which contains among others a column called `Name`
- use those names to replace the `"00000"` placeholders in the template
- output new files `C:\Henry.txt`, `C:\Magy.txt` etcetera

If that assumption is correct, try

```
$template = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Config.txt'
(Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Whatever-PREP.csv').Name | ForEach-Object {
    # replace "00000" with the name (represented by `$_`) and use that name as filename for the output
    $template -replace '"00000"', ('"{0}"' -f $_) | Set-Content -Path ('C:\{0}.txt' -f $_) -Force
}
```

P.S. Make sure the CSV you are importing uses the *comma* as delimiter character. If this is some other character, add `-Delimiter '<yourCharacter>'` to the cmdlet.

Comment: I tried this morning and it keeps coming back like this                        Import-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\H107371a\Desktop\SELFINSTALL\Untitled131.ps1:2 char:20
+ (Import-Csv  -Path 'CSRLDAM3954591-PREP.csv'.Name) | ForEach-Object {
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Csv],

Comment: @EnriqueTellez Use a complete path to the csv file. Also, you need to put the closing bracket **before** `.Name` as in my answer,

Comment: thank you it worked here is the final code                                                                                              $template = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Config.txt'
(Import-Csv -Path 'C:\CSRLDAM3954591-PREP.csv').Name | ForEach-Object {
    
    $template -replace '00000', ('{0}' -f $_) | Set-Content -Path ('C:\{0}.txt' -f $_) -Force}